# Keep user-speciefic data in memory using Web API

Tags: rest, security, session, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-session

We're developing REST API using Web API for a mobile client.
There is a special need to keep **user specific data on server side** (expensive DAL requests).

What is the best practice to do that?

- The naive way is to keep the data in the Application's memory.
- Considering security issues, we're thinking of using ASP.NET Session.

What would you recommend?
3rd party cloud solution is not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should elaborate your answer about what kind of data you are talking about. The REST service cannot maintain client session, but you can have a server side REST client if you want, which can hold a client session. Another stateless solution to put the session data into a token, and let the service sign the token, so every time your resend the token, the service can accept its content as valid. I am not sure whether you really need a REST service, do you have 3rd party or at least multiple clients?

Comment: If you have expensive queries, I'd suggest you rethink the way you approached your solution. Perhaps CQRS – http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html – can help you making your services more responsive.

Comment: @inf3rno Your suggestion to put the session data into a token sounds good, is it a "good practice"?
The REST client is a hybrid-native mobile app (Cordova), so there's only one type of client. Would you recommend an approach other than REST?

Comment: @gtramontina the queries cost is not changeable - it's a black box.

Comment: @GuyLevinger You can use this token if you want REST: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token . But be aware that REST has many constraints you might not want to fulfill. I suggest you to learn REST on a hobby project rather than on a commercial one, and by this project use something you already know. If you have only a single client, and there is not huge load, then SOA is ok. Another option to use a simple HTTP webapp with JSON response. You can create a CRUD app as well. These solutions do not have to support hyperlinks, client side session, etc... as REST requires.